# Angular Routing with an encoded backslash

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am building in invite/registration form for my site.  The idea is that one user invites another user, which sends a code with a url to register with.  The problem is that the code can have an encoded backslash in it.  When that encoded backslash is processed in Angular, it seems to get decoded and ends up busting the routing.

http://localhost:54464/ang/register/owi0%2fCQCrjzBcwqEORVVHhrICIANGKxtxMJ2Kh91y%2bNhhB%2br06appZzEVPhpkP2C

becomes:

http://localhost:54464/ang/register/owi0/CQCrjzBcwqEORVVHhrICIANGKxtxMJ2Kh91y+NhhB+r06appZzEVPhpkP2C

How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a route like:

```
/register/*code
```

The code will contain the string with the slashes

[source](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.$routeProvider)

It is typically used for path-like url arguments...but I don't see why this wouldn't work for your case.